# ASP.NET mvc strong typed <A> tags

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

i'm not sure, but didn't asp.net mvc 2 provide a way to create strong typed  tags?

Michel

Comment: to be more specific: to achieve something like Andrew says in his answer (strongtyped class / methode) but without the installation of an extra framework

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the T4MVC Templates, you can use view code like this (ASPX engine)

```
<%: Html.ActionLink("About Us", MVC.Home.About()) %>
```

More here: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=T4MVC

Comment: Adding to this answer, Html.ActionLink() will render an <a> tag with the parameters you pass. More info here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.aspx

Comment: thanks for the comment, but the Html.ActionLink only takes strings doesn't it? I thought there were also strong typed versions so if i would rename the controller i would get a compile exception?

Comment: As I noted, you need to use the T4MVC Templates and have them running to use that. check out the link I posted.

Comment: yeah, thanks for that, just thought it was something that was built in the mvc framework in v2. i'm always a bit frightened to install yet another library when it only contributes to a small thing. I'm not saying the T4MVC is a small thing, but sometimes i have to install a big library and use only a part of it, and i'm always a little afraid of possible side effects which i cannot foresee (without going through all the documentation)

Comment: Don't forget that T4MVC is just tooling - you don't need it on the server - so I wouldn't worry too much about adding another library.

Answer (score 4):

[ASP.NET MVC Futures](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/41742) contains a strongly typed action link.   It's implimentation is a bit wacky though (you can read more about that [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/06/02/alternative-to-expressions.aspx)).  Personally I would go with the T4 solution.